# Assigning a value to a variable inside (if exists) sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure that checks if the patientID is exists based on patient name.

```
if exists (select pt.Id from dbo.Patients as pt where ltrim(RTRIM(pt.FirstName))=pt.FirstName and LTRIM(rtrim(pt.LastName))=pt.LastName)
begin
     pID=select pt.Id from dbo.Patients as pt where ltrim(RTRIM(pt.FirstName))=pt.FirstName and LTRIM(rtrim(pt.LastName))=pt.LastName
else
     --increment PatentID
```

Is there a way to not do select query two times

Comment: What do you want pID to contain if the patient is not found?

Comment: @Sparky I want to increment it and insert a new patient record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the variable and then check if it's not null.

```
SELECT @pID = pt.Id from dbo.Patients as pt 
WHERE ltrim(RTRIM(pt.FirstName))=pt.FirstName 
AND LTRIM(rtrim(pt.LastName))=pt.LastName)

IF (@pID IS NULL)
BEGIN
   --increment PatientID 
   SELECT @pID = MAX(Id) + 1 FROM dbo.Patients 
   -- insert new record 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pID = select MAX(pt.Id) from dbo.Patients as pt where trim(RTRIM(pt.FirstName))=pt.FirstName and LTRIM(rtrim(pt.LastName))=pt.LastName;

IF @pID  IS NULL
 --Increment
```